# Calculate $\frac{\partial g^2}{\partial\theta\partial r}$, where $g$ is a composition of functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is a twice differentiable function
>   whose Hessian at the point $a = (1,1)$ is:
>
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  -1&2\\ 2&1 \end{bmatrix}
>
> Let $g(r,\theta) = f\circ h = f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$, then
>   calculate $\frac{\partial g^2}{\partial\theta\partial r}(\sqrt{2},\pi/4)$.

I'm not sure on how to translate the formula for the chain rule to the second derivative. (If it weren't the second derivative, it'd be easy given that $h(\sqrt 2, \pi/4) = (1,1)$.)

So, how could I solve the exercise?

Comment: Are you able to apply the chain rule to $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} \right)$?

Comment: How, if I don't have an explicit formula for $f$ or the Jacobian of $f$?

Comment: You asked how to proceed to apply the chain rule for the second derivative.  Now you are asking something else.  The Question appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Since you didn't show any of your work, it is impossible to guess with what you are having trouble.

Comment: I think I phrased the question incorrectly. I meant it as, how do I solve the exercise. Not specifically on how to apply the chain rule.

Comment: ... still haven't shown your work.  From the pop-up when you clicked "Ask Question":  "... describe what you’ve tried."

Comment: My work was trying to apply the chain rule. Which failed.

Comment: The Chain rule cannot "fail".  Again, it is impossible to guess where you are having difficulty from this complete lack of information.

Comment: You said that the hessian of that function is that matrix, but the hessian is only a matrix if your function is $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and is that case it will be a n by n matrix. in you case $f$ is defined as $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and in that case the hessian will not be that matrix. In fact, it will be a rank 3 tensor

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @Eduude. I've edited the question.

Comment: If the solution is supposed to be a number, then you also need to know the values of the first derivatives of $f$. Otherwise, you’ll have to leave it as an expression that involves $\nabla f$.

Comment: There's no way of knowing the first derivatives of $f$. Are you positive that's the case? From the way the exercise is worded, it seems like we're supposed to give a numerical value (therefore it should be possible to do so solely with the information given).